# How to select the same column twice with different order

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my problem. I need to order the same colum in diferent ways in the same select. First asc and then desc.

Example:

**Table1**

```
+--------+-----+
| Name   | Age |
+--------+-----+
| Coa    | 20  |
| Bami   | 12  |
| Alice  | 50  |
+--------+-----+
```

The results should be:

```
+------+-----+
| Age  | Age |
+------+-----+
| 12   | 50  |
| 20   | 20  |
| 50   | 12  |
+------+-----+
```

I want the same column first orders Ascendant and then Descendant.

I am trying

**Query**

```
Select t1.age, t2.age
from table1 t1 
inner join table1 t2 
on t1.name=t2.name
order by t1.age asc, t2.age desc
```

But in the result, both columns ordered in the same way.

Anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a really weird requirement.  You can do this using `row_number()` and a join:

```
select t1a.age, t1b.age
from (select t1.*, row_number() over (order by age asc) as seqnum
      from table1 t1
     ) t1a join
     (select t1.*, row_number() over (order by age desc) as seqnum
      from t1
     ) t1b
     on t1a.seqnum = t1b.seqnum
order by t1a.age;
```

Comment: thx! problem solved! But I still am trying to understand why the "order by" in my comand was odering then in equal order even when specifying to do it in differrent ways.

Comment: @DuroForce . . . The `order by` keys order *rows* by each key.  The second key is only being used for rows that have equal values of the first key.

Answer (score 2):

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/02a4c/1)

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT NAME,
            AGE,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY AGE ASC) AS AC,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY AGE DESC) AS DC
    FROM YOURTABLE
)

SELECT C1.AGE,C2.AGE
FROM CTE C1 
        INNER JOIN CTE C2 ON C1.AC=C2.DC
```